# How to disable some radio buttons with css

Tags: css, sass

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acLeb.png)I want to disable only parent nodes, 'Plants','Animals', 'Mammals', and 'Invertebrates', here is my code, but it is not working. keep other radio buttons enable, the structure of the code is final, I cant change the structure of my code

```css
.list-unstyled>li {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    opacity: 0.4;
    pointer-events: none
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li> <input type="radio"> Plants </label>
      <ul style="list-style:none" class="ng-scope">
        <li> <label class="ng-binding ng-scope"><input type="radio" > Crops </label>
          <ul style="list-style:none" class="ng-scope"></ul>
        </li>
        <li> <label class="ng-binding ng-scope"><input type="radio"> Trees </label>
          <ul style="list-style:none" class="ng-scope"></ul>
        </li>
        <li> <label class="ng-binding ng-scope"><input type="radio"> Ornamentals </label>
          <ul style="list-style:none" class="ng-scope"></ul>
        </li>
        <li> <label class="ng-binding ng-scope"> <input type="radio"> Algae </label>
          <ul style="list-style:none" class="ng-scope"></ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <label class="ng-binding ng-scope"><input type="radio"> Animals </label>
      <ul>
        <li> <label class="ng-binding ng-scope"><input type="radio" > Vertebrates </label>
          <ul style="list-style:none" class="ng-scope">
            <li> <label> Mammals </label>
              <ul style="list-style:none" class="ng-scope"></ul>
            </li>
            <li> <label class="ng-binding ng-scope"><input type="radio"> Birds </label>
              <ul style="list-style:none" class="ng-scope"></ul>
          </ul>
          </li>
          <li> <input type="radio"> Invertebrates </label>
            <ul style="list-style:none" class="ng-scope">
              <li> <label class="ng-binding ng-scope"><input type="radio"> Insects </label>
                <ul style="list-style:none" class="ng-scope"></ul>
              </li>
              <li> <label class="ng-binding ng-scope"><input type="radio"> Arachnids </label>
                <ul style="list-style:none" class="ng-scope"></ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <label class="ng-binding ng-scope"><input input type="radio"> Fungi </label>
        <ul style="list-style:none" class="ng-scope"></ul>
      </li> <input input type="radio"></label> xxxx
      <ul style="list-style:none" class="ng-scope"></ul>
    </li>
    <li> <input input type="radio"></label>yyyyy
      <ul style="list-style:none" class="ng-scope"></ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBPqD.png)

Comment: You've got some [code errors](https://jsfiddle.net/upr7qkwm/)

Answer (score 0):

Please use This code

```
.list-unstyled > li > label  {
cursor: not-allowed;
opacity: 0.4;
pointer-events: none
```

}

And you have miss one li start XXXX label

Comment: actually when select an Ii, it disable all its ul, and I need to disable only first li inside ul

Comment: how to handle it using jquery